# Google App Scripts & Google Sheets - Equivalent of VLOOKUP/IMPORTRANGE - Using multiple spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

**Objective:**
I would like to eliminate the use of formulas (array formulas, importranges, and vlookups). Instead, I would like to use Google App Script to populate columns in the Child Database Spreadsheet. *This is because of the current performance issues every time I open the sheet, and issues with Google Data Studio timing out when pulling the data.*

---

**I have 2 spreadsheets.**

**#1 - Master Database** (~1,000,000 rows) - 100% Manual Input

|  | A (Manual Input) | B (Manual Input) | C (Manual Input) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X123456 | John Doe | JohnDoe@examplecom |
| 2 | X987654 | Jane Smith | JaneSmith@examplecom |
| 3 | X543210 | Sarah Smith | SarahSmith@examplecom |

---

**#2 - Child Database** (~10,000 rows)

**Its purpose:** Manually enter ID's in Col A, and the formula will auto-populate Col B:C (Name & Email)

- This is the expected results with GAS instead of the current formula.

|  | A (Manual Input) | B (Auto-Populate) | C (Auto-Populate) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X543210 | Sarah Smith | SarahSmith@examplecom |
| 2 | X123456 | John Doe | JohnDoe@examplecom |

- Col A - Manual Input of ID.
- Col B1 contains formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,IMPORTRANGE("URL","MasterDB!A2:C"),{2,3},FALSE))`  *which get's the ID's from Col A, searches the Master Database spreadsheet, and returns the Name, and Email.*

---

**What is the best solution?**

Here is what I came up with, so far...

```
function myFunction() {
  //Source Info.
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC');
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName("MasterDB");
  const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:A").getValues; //Get's ID's from Master Spreadsheet

  //Destination Info.
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ');
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("ChildDB");
  const cDB = dsh.getRange("A2:A").getValues; //Get's ID's from Child Spreadsheet

  [Some Code Here]
  - Return Col B,C from Master Sheet, if Col A matches in both Master & Child Sheet.

}
```

Thanks for any of your input, guidance, and help :)

Comment: Range like `"A2:A"` will cause problems by generating lots of nulls  at the end of data.  Replace with `getRange(row,col,numrow,numcols)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:A").getValues;` and `const cDB = dsh.getRange("A2:A").getValues;` are required to be added `()` for executing the function of `getValues`.
- It seems that `import` of the function name is the reserved name. So please modify the function name. When V8 runtime is used.

When these points are reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC');
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName("MasterDB");
  const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:C" + ssh.getLastRow()).getValues(); //Get's ID's from Master Spreadsheet

  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ');
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("ChildDB");
  const cDB = dsh.getRange("A2:A" + dsh.getLastRow()).getValues(); //Get's ID's from Child Spreadsheet

  // Create an object for searching the values of column "A".
  const obj = mDB.reduce((o, [a, ...bc]) => ((o[a] = bc), o), {});
  
  // Create an array for putting to the Spreadsheet.
  const values = cDB.map(([b]) => obj[b] || ["", ""]);
  
  // Put the array to the Spreadsheet.
  dsh.getRange(2, 2, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

- In order to achieve your goal, I modified the sample script at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69805150/7108653).

#### Note:

- This script is used with V8 runtime. So when you disable V8 runtime, please enable it.
- If this was not the result you expect, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to modify the script.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

About your new 3 questions, I answered as follows.

> [Question #1] I assume o is just a placeholder and can be any letter I want. Is that true? or does the letter o have some significant?

Yes. You can use other variable name except for `o`. In this script, the initial value of `o` is `{}`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> [Question #2] What do the 3 dots do? [a, ...bc] ?

`...` is spread syntax. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

> [Question #3] How would I skip a returned column? Currently it returns b,c. How would I return c,d instead?

In this case, the sample script is as follows.

```js
function Q69818704_myFunction() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC');
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName("MasterDB");
  const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:D" + ssh.getLastRow()).getValues();

  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ');
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("ChildDB");
  const cDB = dsh.getRange("A2:A" + dsh.getLastRow()).getValues();

  const obj = mDB.reduce((o, [a,, ...cd]) => ((o[a] = cd), o), {});
  const values = cDB.map(([b]) => obj[b] || ["", ""]);
  dsh.getRange(2, 2, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Wow, the performance of this script is very fast, but I have no idea how your advanced code works / how to edit it haha. Thank you for the solution! Ill get researching on how reduce() and map() works.

Comment: [Question #1] I assume `o` is just a placeholder and can be any letter I want. Is that true? or does the letter `o` have some significant?

Comment: [Question #2] What do the 3 dots do? `[a, ...bc]` ?

Comment: [Question #3] How would I skip a returned column? Currently it returns b,c. How would I return c,d instead?

Comment: @JamesReed68 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 1st question was resolved. About your new 3 questions, I added the 3 answers. Could you please confirm it? If my 3 answers to your additional 3 questions were not useful, I apologize.