# Google App Script that replicates VLOOKUP

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

#### Is there an option using Google App Scripts that works like VLOOKUP?

I am hoping for a solution that will replace the `???` on Spreadsheet 2, with the emails on Spreadsheet 1 on a scheduled bases using the GAS trigger feature.

**Currently I am using formulas, but they are slowing down the performance of my sheets. I don't need them fetching data more than once every 24 hours, hence why I am wanting to use GAS instead with a trigger.**

- IMPORTRANGE & QUERY to import Spreadsheet #1 (ID, Email 1, Email2) to Spreadsheet #2
  `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, A1:E), "SELECT Col1,Col4,Col5 WHERE A Col1 is not null", 1)`
- Then on Spreadsheet #2 using ARRAYFORMULA & VLOOKUP to populate all the emails.
  `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2:A,ImportedData!A2:C},{2,3},0)`

**Here are what my 2 spreadsheets look like...**

##### Spreadsheet #1 (Contains ~2 million cells)

| ID | Something | Something | Email1 | Email2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | * | * | Bob@hotmail.com | Bob@gmail.com |
| 222222 | * | * | James@gmail.com | James@yahoo.com |

##### Spreadsheet #2 (Contains ~200k cells)

| ID | Email 1 | Email 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | ??? | ??? |
| 222222 | ??? | ??? |

---

### UPDATE

I asked a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69818704/) and received an answer.

The answer was:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC');
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName("MasterDB");
  const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:C" + ssh.getLastRow()).getValues(); //Get's ID's from Master Spreadsheet

  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ');
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("ChildDB");
  const cDB = dsh.getRange("A2:A" + dsh.getLastRow()).getValues(); //Get's ID's from Child Spreadsheet

  // Create an object for searching the values of column "A".
  const obj = mDB.reduce((o, [a, ...bc]) => ((o[a] = bc), o), {});
  
  // Create an array for putting to the Spreadsheet.
  const values = cDB.map(([b]) => obj[b] || ["", ""]);
  
  // Put the array to the Spreadsheet.
  dsh.getRange(2, 2, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

#### My New Question (for this thread)

How do I modify the script to exclude column B and C?

Comment: I think that your goal might be able to be achieved using Google Apps Script. But, in your question, also I think that when you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: I just updated it now. The tables were giving me an error so I posted the question without them temporarily. Hopefully that helps visualize the data, and add context to my question. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69818704/google-app-scripts-google-sheets-equivalent-of-vlookup-importrange-using-m

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thank yo for replying and adding more information. As TheMaster's comment, also I thought that in your situation when the sample script of https://stackoverflow.com/a/69819156 as follows, your goal might be able to be achieved. From `const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:C" + ssh.getLastRow()).getValues();` to `const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:E" + ssh.getLastRow()).getValues()`, and from `const obj = mDB.reduce((o, [a, ...bc]) => ((o[a] = bc), o), {})` to `const obj = mDB.reduce((o, [a,,,...de]) => ((o[a] = de), o), {})`. How about this? If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: @TheMaster Your right! That question is very similar to the one I just posted. The only difference being that there are additional columns in the Source which I need to omit from the Destination. In the past, I have been downvoted for asking a new question on my existing post, so I thought it would be better to post as a new question. But I can see how that looks bad also. I'll be sure to reference to a previous question URL next time. Thanks :)

Comment: @JamesReed68 New question is ok, but differentiate it clearly. And most importantly, show what you tried. SO is NOT a free code writing service. Don't treat community members like free code writers.

Comment: Didn't [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389863/google-app-script-that-replicates-vlookup#comment124427477_70389863) resolve your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike The revisions you made worked perfectly. Thank you for sharing a solution despite how my original question appeared to be seeking a free code writing service. I updated my question on this thread. Can you repost your answer so I can mark it as the answer? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I posted my comment as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I think that your goal might be able to be achieved by the following 2 modification points in your script.

#### From:

```
const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:C" + ssh.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
const mDB = ssh.getRange("A2:E" + ssh.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

And also, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
const obj = mDB.reduce((o, [a, ...bc]) => ((o[a] = bc), o), {});
```

#### To:

```
const obj = mDB.reduce((o, [a,,,...de]) => ((o[a] = de), o), {});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for your solution. Using your answer here, and the one from the previous question I can now cross reference both, and visualize what parts of the code to change based on my application (example: there being more than 2 columns to omit).