# How to concat multiple ranges

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to perform a similar VLOOKUP as described in this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/VemzjFWBdM4) where I'm pulling info from multiple separate workbooks using google apps script to avoid a very cumbersome formula with multiple links. I've used the solution provided in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69818704/google-app-scripts-google-sheets-equivalent-of-vlookup-importrange-using-m). I have a master sheet containing record IDs (column A) that will receive data from various workbooks when the record ID is found. In my master workbook there is also a sheet with the IDs of the various workbooks.

I believe the issue with my code is within the ForEach block. Each vs range is treated separately. So the first range executes and pastes into the master, then the second executes and pastes into the master BUT replaces what was put there from the first range, and so forth. Can I concat all the ranges into one array to prevent loss of information from the previous execution? Is that the solution here?

`

```
function updateMaster() {
  const mss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const msh = mss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const mDB = msh.getRange("A2:A" + msh.getLastRow()).getValues(); //Gets ID's from Master Spreadsheet

  const ish = mss.getSheetByName('Sheet IDs'); 
  const ivs = ish.getRange('A1:A' + ish.getLastRow()).getValues().flat(); 
  ivs.forEach((id,i) => {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sep 22');
    let vs = sh.getRange("A2:L" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();  //Get's ID's from individual sheets
    Logger.log(vs)

  // Create an object for searching the values of column "A".
  const obj = vs.reduce((o, [a,,,,,,,,,, ...kl]) => ((o[a] = kl), o), {});
  
  // Create an array for putting to the Spreadsheet.
  const values = mDB.map(([g]) => obj[g] || ["", ""]);

  // Put the array to the Spreadsheet.
  msh.getRange(2, 7, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
    });
}
```

`

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your input and output situations. So, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for assisting. I have added a link to sample data. I am expecting the data in columns K and L of Spreadsheets 1 and 2 to be added to Master in G and H by matching the record IDs in column A.

Comment: The range for your `master` sheet should be set dynamically. What you have there is the same set of range or fixed range. So, whenever you `setValues()` to your master sheet it's the same range. This can be achieved by determining the `index`  using common methods `indexOf()`  or `findIndex()`of the matched id from the master sheet and use it as reference for your row position, i.e .`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`. Another thing, there should be `conditional statements` included in the code in case the same `id` appears multiple times from any sheets, what should be done then?...

Comment: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** ([NOT as IMAGE](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)/Spreadsheet LINK) to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't [self contained](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that the discussions have already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussions.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've resolved the issue. There may be a better way but this works for now. I simply added the empty array of combinedData then added the concat method for each range returned from the fileIDs. This way the values from each workbook are mapped and set to the master as opposed to the previous being overwritten by the next iteration.

```js
function updateMaster() {
  const mss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const msh = mss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const mDB = msh.getRange("A2:A" + msh.getLastRow()).getValues(); //Gets ID's from Master Spreadsheet

  var combinedData = [];   // edited

  const ish = mss.getSheetByName('Sheet IDs'); 
  const ivs = ish.getRange('A1:A' + ish.getLastRow()).getValues().flat(); 
  ivs.forEach((id,i) => {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sep 22');
    let vs = sh.getRange("A2:L" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();  //Get's ID's from individual sheets
    combinedData = combinedData.concat(vs);  // edited
    Logger.log(combinedData)

  // Create an object for searching the values of column "A".
  const obj = combinedData.reduce((o, [a,,,,,,,,,, ...kl]) => ((o[a] = kl), o), {});
  
  // Create an array for putting to the Spreadsheet.
  const values = mDB.map(([g]) => obj[g] || ["", ""]);

  // Put the array to the Spreadsheet.
  msh.getRange(2, 7, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
    });
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

While I realize your question states "*avoid a very cumbersome formula with multiple links*"

I would challenge you that your code (which doesn't work) is far more cumbersome than this [query formula](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/), which appears to achieve exactly what you want. It's just two [ImportRange Formulas](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) that only have two parameters, fileID and ranges, which you clearly have. Then the only complex part is just a sql statement that sorts by first column and removes null values... which is: `Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1`

Final result of formula:

```
=Query({
  IMPORTRANGE("1I_JrTV-2f3NW99H-YhwrIQ2XCBrYpFBgv_Zgk9aw0kY","A:H");
  IMPORTRANGE("10VnARaD6undBuUt-dGl-IDvQiuOw8F2CXOawGYOda0c","A:H")},
  "Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1")
```

[image]

If you need a dynamic list you could do something like this where column E and F represent your sheetID and Ranges to pull:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, y, QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(MAP(x, y, 
 LAMBDA(e, f, QUERY("♣"&FLATTEN(QUERY("♥"&TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE(e, f)),,9^9)),,9^9))),,9^9), 
 "♣")), "♥"), "where Col1 <> ' ' order by Col2", 1))(
 E2:INDEX(E:E, MAX((E:E<>"")*ROW(E:E))), 
 F2:INDEX(F:F, MAX((F:F<>"")*ROW(F:F)))))
```

Comment: Thanks @pgSystemTester. I'm quite familiar with query and importrange. I've only provided two sheets as samples for this question but in reality I could end up with more than 20 sheets, hence the script route. Creating a list of fileIDs in a sheet may be more manageable compared to a formula.

Comment: @Jamie see updated. Maybe it's complex formula (okay it is...), but still has less syntax than your script, plus it calculates instantly and doesn't require you to compromise your security and it's instantaneous... Either way, fun challenge. Good luck.